# Display recent members

Tags: users

I have the following code who should work fine. But Wordpress is crashing. What's wrong?

```
echo "<ul>";
$usernames = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_nicename, user_url FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5");
foreach ($usernames as $username) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$username->user_url.'">'.$username->user_nicename."</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: What does it mean "crashing"? Please _edit the question_ providing enough information.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the above code, it works for me.  You must have another error outside of the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the `get_users` function.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

Example:

`get_users('orderby=meta_value&meta_key=user_registered');`